# Which formula for entropy is correct? (OR Is the fundamental thermodynamic equality always right?)

Tags: thermodynamics

Quick question, in the lecture notes to a thermodynamic course I'm taking,

$$d\underline{S}=\frac{d\underline{U}}{T}+\Big(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\Big)_{\underline{V}} d\underline{V}$$

But everywhere else I've looked I've found (by rearranging the fundamental thermodynamic relation:

$$d\underline{S}=\frac{d\underline{U}}{T}+\frac{P}{T}d\underline{V}$$

The two are obviously extremely similar, however I don't believe they're equivalent in general (I believe you'd have to make further assumptions about the system, particularly $P=kT$ at constant specific volume, to go from one to the other.)

Right now I'm just asking if anyone knows which relation is the more general. I was of the opinion that the fundamental thermodynamic relation was always correct, but now I'm doubting myself. Thanks.

Comment: I've always thought of (hydrostatic) pressure as being *defined* by the fundamental relation, which implies that your second equation is the correct one. Your second equation is very familiar to me but I've never seen the first one before. I would post this as an answer, but I'd prefer to understand more about where the first equation comes from before I state outright that it's wrong - in your first equation $P$ is a function of $T$ and $V$, whereas in the second it's $U$ and $V$. So I suspect that it might be correct but saying something different from your second equation.

Comment: That's a fascinating idea - pressure is defined by this relation (is there a particular text that presents thermodynamics that way?) I haven't actually encountered a derivation for the first equation anywhere, indeed I don't know of a textbook that gives it. I *can* tell you we need to use the first equation when given an equation of state of the form $P = f(T,\underline{V})$ (the simplest of which is the ideal gas law). So you might be onto something ...

Comment: BTW - how do you know $P$ is a function of $T$ and $U$ in the second equation? Why not $S$ or another thermodynamic quantity?

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with a reference for pressure being defined that way. I probably picked it up from one of many papers by Edwin Jaynes. I can tell that $P$ is a function of $T$ and $U$ from the notation $$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V,$$ which means "vary $T$ while keeping $V$ constant". (Personally I find it a somewhat confusing notation and usually prefer to write it as $$\frac{\partial P(T, V)}{\partial T},$$ which is what it really means. But the way you've written it is very standard in thermodynamics.)

Comment: The notes are no good, the second equation is right, the first is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both seem a little strange. So let us see where they are coming from. What we know is from the laws of thermodynamics that the total differential of the internal energy $U$ can be written as $$dU = \delta Q + dW$$
Here $\delta Q$ is an infinitesimal amound of thermal energy and $dW$ an infinitesimal amount of work. The work is the product of a generalized displacement times a generalized force, which are together a conjugated pair of variables. One such pair is pressure and volume, $P\, dV$. For a reversible process $\delta Q = T dS$, so that we get
$$dU = T\,dS - P\,dV$$
From here we easily arrive at your second equation:
$$ \frac{dU}{T} + \frac{P}{T} dV = dS$$
Now we compare with your first equation, which can only be true if$$\frac{P}{T} = \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V$$
which  certainly does not hold for all thermodynamic systems. So your first equation is more general and the second one only correct in specific circumstances. We rearrange the condition $$P(T,V) = \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V T$$ which can only be satisfied by a general function $f(V)$ and $$P(T,V) = f(V) \,T$$

Comment: Thankyou very much, that's fantastic, and makes 100% sense :) I must admit I'm slightly disturbed by your reply though, considering that in a 3rd year chemical engineering course we have freely been using the first equation with EOS's like $P = \frac{RT}{V-b}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{T}V_m(V_m+b)}$ (a common EOS called the Reidlich-Kwong EOS) which certainly doesn't obey your criterion :(

Comment: Sorry, did you mean the *second* equation is more general (considering you derived it)? :)

Comment: @tom: Sorry for the confusion, I wanted to say: my first equation, which is your second equation. In short $\frac{dU}{T} + \frac{P}{T} dV = dS$ is correct and general.